# PHP XML request to SOAP WebService

Tags: php, web-services, soap

Sorry if i am asking something that was already discussed here but all my combinations that i tryed are not working. I am not PHP developer but i am trying create PHP sample that will send request to my SOAP asp.net webservice and to echo the response.

I am trying to use the following PHP code:

```
$soapUrl = "https://test-api.xxxx.xx/reseller.asmx?op=loginXML";

$xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap12:Body><loginXML xmlns="https://test-api.zemi.mk/"><acckey>adsdsad</acckey><password>pass</password></loginXML></soap12:Body></soap12:Envelope>';

$headers = array(
"POST /reseller.asmx HTTP/1.1",
"Host: test-api.*****.**",
"Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
"Content-Length: ".strlen($xml_post_string)
); 

$url = $soapUrl;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

$response1 = str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$response);
$response2 = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$response1);

$parser = simplexml_load_string($response2);

echo $parser;
```

But it does not work. 
What i am seeing then i am trying to execute is:

```
$soapUrl = "https://test-api.++++.++/reseller.asmx?op=loginXML"; $xml_post_string = 'adsdsadpass'; $headers = array( "POST /reseller.asmx HTTP/1.1", "Host: test-api.++++.++", "Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8", "Content-Length: ".strlen($xml_post_string) ); $url = $soapUrl; $ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); $response = curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch); $response1 = str_replace("","",$response); $response2 = str_replace("","",$response1); $parser = simplexml_load_string($response2); echo $parser;
```

Can u help me what i am doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Please add additional information as to what doesn't work...

Comment: when i am trying to execute this code it shows me the whole code without XML tags on the screen

Comment: _"it shows me the whole code without XML tags"_ - What code? The above PHP code? Or do you mean that you see all the XML data from the response without the tags? Then check the page source and see if you can see it there.

Comment: i just edit my question with the result that i am getting.

Comment: Ok, so you're getting the actual PHP-code. How are you executing this code? Through a browser/web server? Double clicking on the file? Got PHP installed? (btw, instead of creating your own Soap request, why not use PHP's [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php)?)

Comment: i am testing server that is  runing Plesk panel. It has PHP installed on it and i am executing through browser.

Comment: Actualy why i was getting the code because i havent put php tag <?php ?> but now i am not getting any response after running this.